# A declined spam flag on a post with linked punctuation, what gives?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, spam

I flagged this post as spam:

- [How to get the unix directory(multiple paths under same directory) size, usage and free size in MB using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713876/how-to-get-the-unix-directorymultiple-paths-under-same-directory-size-usage-a/61713999#61713999)

It got declined:

[image]

The markdown of the post was:

```
<p>I don't know how to code but it helps<a href="Spam link" rel="nofollow noreferrer">.</a></p>
```

What gives?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That was my mistake. I missed the link in the full stop.

Normally when I see a spam flag on something with no obvious link I run my cursor over all the text and check the source for links by editing the post, but in this case I missed it.

I can't undo the action on the flag but I can undelete the post and reflag it as spam and deal with the account.

Sorry about that.

Comment: Why not click the edit button? Sometimes there is some HTML stuff hidden and not displayed.

Comment: @Dharman - that's what I meant by checking the source.

Comment: Just an FYI: There is a way to change a declined spam flag into disputed. I don't think you can get it to helpful, but disputed is better. I don't know the process, but other moderators have mentioned on MSO that they've done so. As a side note: how to do so doesn't appear to be known to a good number of moderators, as I've mentioned to a couple on other sites and they didn't know how to do it either. I'd have to look around to see which moderators have mentioned doing it here on MSO.

Comment: @makyen, yes I could do that but it's only one flag and I'm sure the OP will raise many more helpful flags. Especially as I'll be more careful!

Comment: I actually just did what @Makyen suggested, before reading his comment. While I don't know of a way to change declined red flags into helpful ones, they can be retroactively disputed, which changes *all* red flags that have been raised on a post. (I then re-flagged as spam.) Aside from the fact that disputed flags don't count against the flagger (not that this really matters), it makes me happier, as it's a better signal to the system about what actually happened.

Comment: In my defence for not disputing the flag last night - it was late and I was on mobile and moderating on mobile is difficult at the best of times.

Comment: By way of suggestion, you could set up a userscript to highlight all links inside posts on the moderator review pages. I did that for suggested edit reviews after I realized I missed a link.