# What should be done about spam edited in to otherwise legitimate-looking questions after they've been answered?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I encountered this question: [How Can i Push Latest Project Files From Git To Gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68112416/1364007) (now deleted) which was asked yesterday, had two answers (one of which was accepted), then it was closed. A couple of hours ago, the OP edited it to include a spam link in the first comma in the first line of the question - I've redacted the link in the quote:

> When I open Git bash it is not pushing the latest file and gives the error[,](https://www.example.com) My latest Commits are not going to the GitLab Project Repository.
> Can anyone please describe the steps after updating the project to push to the Gitlab Repository.
> I'm new here and need help from seniors.

The link was obviously spam - I confirmed it using [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com/).

I raised a spam flag, because it's spam (albeit non-obvious).

That flag was then declined with the standard message:

[image: declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it]

At this point I can only think of three other things I should have done differently:

1. **Edited the spam out**

   As the spam was edited into the question at a point when it (a) had answers, and (b) looked like a legitimate question up to that point.

   Based on "[Is it OK to edit obvious spam to break links?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263051/1364007)" and "[Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/284827)" it seems that I should *not* have done this. Especially since the spam link would still be visible in the history of the question.
2. **Raised a *custom* flag**

   Moderators are obviously very busy and subsequently may not spot linked punctuation so easily, e.g. "[A declined spam flag on a post with linked punctuation, what gives?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397330/1364007)" This is especially likely if the post is given some credibility by having been answered beforehand.

   Raising a custom flag seemed like overkill because the question wasn't great before the spam was added (which is why it was closed) so I opted to go for a standard spam flag instead. In retrospect this was a mistake.
3. **Ignore it**

   This is obviously not ideal, because the problem is still there.

Should I have just raised a custom flag from the outset? What should I do now - presumably raise a custom flag?

Comment: 2.  Yes, 2. Please 2.

Comment: Aha - I see that the question (and the user) have now been dealt with, and the status of my flag has switched from 'declined' to 'disputed'. In future I'll go with the custom flag route. Thanks for taking care of this.

Comment: In your custom flag, you can link to [this helpful userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js), which emphasizes links created with really short link text (e.g., single digits or punctuation characters). :-)